# Google sheets script - copy paste values from one column to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with copy/paste script.
I have column B (with formulas). I want to create new column after B, so it will be C and after that copy values from B to column C.

I have that:

```js
function copyData() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
     sh.insertColumnAfter(2); 
     var range = sh.getRange("B1:B20");
     var values = range.getValues();
     var add = sh.getRange("C1:C20");
     add.setValue(values);
}
```

After use that script I have new column, but whole column has values only from cell B1 (in 20 rows the same).
Can someone tell my why this is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setValue() of an array only pasting one of the values in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991421/setvalue-of-an-array-only-pasting-one-of-the-values-in-the-array)

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line to

```
add.setValues(values);
```

The var 'values' is a two-dimensional array. If you use setValue() only the first value (top of the range) will be set to the whole target range.

Reference: [.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))