# Automatically save column to different google sheet every month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My Spreadsheet has two Sub Sheets  "Sheet 1" and "Sheet 2".
Column A on "Sheet 1" receives new data every month.  (old data is overwritten)
I need script to automatically copy Column A data once a month and move it to "sheet 2"
Of course on "sheet 2" Column A would be the landing spot for this month and next month the landing spot would be Column B and so on, so that a history is preserved.

I thought I could to this... but didn't realize just how much I didn't know.  Any help is appreciated

```
`function storeData(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); // Select Spreadsheet by ID
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); // Select your Sheet by its Name
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange(A1:A150);`
```

this is as far I can get

Comment: Hi and welcome. We've all been there and done that. My personal suggestion is use StackOverflow (and other resouyrces) to find questions that are the same or similar to yours. For example: [Google sheets script - copy paste values from one column to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592693/1330560) is VERY similar to yours except that it copies the data onto the same sheet and [setValue() of an array only pasting one of the values in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991504/1330560) uses some more useful methods.

Comment: Just to touch on your code... `getDataRange()` doesn't take an attribute [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange). That's its advantage - you can grab ALL of the data on a sheet with just one line and without having to find the start/finish row & column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID')`

  - you don't need to reference by ID if everything is happening in the active spreadsheet
- `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1')`

  - maybe your sheet name **is** "Sheet 1", but the default sheet names don't contain a space. Just make sure of the name of your sheet.
- `var datarange = sheet.getDataRange(A1:A150);`

  - you don't add a specific range when you use `getDataRange`. BUT if you put ANY data in any column other than Column A then you should use a different method to declare the source range. For example: `var targetRange = target.getRange(1,targetLC,sourceValues.length)`. If the data in Column A isn't contiguous then you'll want to `flat` the values - that's something that you can learn about if/when you need to.
- the `Logger.log` statements have been left in to help with debugging, but once your script is working OK you can escape them.
- Google is your friend. Use StackOverflow (and other resources) to find answers to questions like your own.

---

```
function storeData(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var sourceRange = source.getDataRange()
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues()
  Logger.log(sourceValues)
  Logger.log("the number of rows of source data = "+sourceValues.length)

  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  // get the last Column on target sheet
  // note: if column A is blank, the last column will = 1
  // BUT if column A has data and column B is blanbk, then the last column will still = 1
  // so need to test whether Column A on the target contains any data
  // we'll use ISBLANK - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank

  var targetA1 = target.getDataRange()
  Logger.log(targetA1.isBlank())
  
  if (targetA1.isBlank() == true){
    // range is blank, so Last Column = 1
    var targetLC = 1
    Logger.log("Column A is blank")
  }
  else{
    // range is not blank, so last column <>1
    var targetLC = target.getLastColumn()+1
    Logger.log("the last column on the target sheet = "+targetLC)
  }
  var targetRange = target.getRange(1,targetLC,sourceValues.length)
  Logger.log("The target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues)
  Logger.log("copies the data")

}
```

Comment: var targetRange = target.getRange(1,targetLC,sourceValues.length)       I will need to use this.   What does "1" represent?  column 1 as in A,  such that a "2" in this spot would equal column B

Comment: my source column is "E"...and there is other Data in column F

Comment: "var targetRange = target.getRange(1,targetLC,sourceValues.length)... What does "1" represent?" Read the [documentation shows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column); there are 5(five) different methods for declaring a range. _This_ method has three attributes: row, column, and numRows (indexing starts with 1). So the `1`= Row1, `targetLC` = `target.getLastColumn()+1` (last Column plus 1), and number of columns = `sourceValues.length` number of records in the array. `Logger.log("The target range = "+targetRange.getA1Notation())` = the range.

Comment: "such that a "2" in this spot would equal column B". No. Read the documentation. [getLastColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) "returns the position of the last column that has content". Each time that you run the update, the data is copied to the column that is one column to the right of the last update. Since we don't keep track of updates, the solution is to return the index value of `getLastColumn()` = the column containing the last update. So... next update will go into `getLastColumn()+1` (`var targetLC = target.getLastColumn()+1`).

Comment: My apologies Tedinoz,  I did present the problem in the most basic form, without realizing that the devil would be in the details.  I was able to have your solution work.  By creating an additional sheet tab to reposition the data for cherry picking.